# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos {ax}}{\cosh{x}}dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, improper-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration

$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\cos {ax}}{\cosh{x}}dx$

$a$ is a real number.
Hint: Consider a suitable rectangular contour

I know that $\frac{1}{\cosh z}$ has simple poles when $z=\frac{(2n-1)\pi}{2}i$.

What should I do next?
I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can apply Cauchy's residue theorem here in the limit sense even if there are infinitely many poles. See [Cauchy's residue theorem with an infinite number of poles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205057/cauchys-residue-theorem-with-an-infinite-number-of-poles?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Welcome to the site! Here, we look for questions that do more than just pose a problem. What is the motivation for this problem? Where does the integral arise? Were did you encounter it (what is the source)?  This information makes posts more interesting to others and helps them write more informative answers. You can edit the post to add this additional context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let us notice that the function $\cos (ax) / \cosh (x)$ does not change under $x \mapsto -x$. So,

$$
\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{\cos ax}{\cosh x} \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos ax} {\cosh x} \, dx.
$$

Next, we should take the contour $\gamma_M$ to be like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA0LZ.jpg). Line (1) is a part of real line $[-M, \, M]$, and the upper line (3) is the same line translated by $\pi i$.

The integral over line (3) could be rewritten as

$$
\int\limits_{(3)} \frac{\cos ax}{ \cosh x} \, dx = \int\limits_{(1)} \frac{\cos a(x + \pi i)}{\cosh (x + \pi i)} \, dx = (*).
$$

Notice, that $\cosh (x + \pi i) = - \cosh x$ and

$$
\cos a (x + \pi i) = \cos (ax) \cos ( a \pi i) - \sin (ax) \sin ( a \pi i).
$$

Therefore,

$$
(*) = \cos (a \pi i )\int\limits_{(1)} \frac{\cos a x}{\cosh x} \, dx - \sin (a \pi i) \int\limits_{(1)} \frac{\sin a x}{\cosh x} \, dx.
$$

Last integral clearly equals zero, as it is the sum of symmetric and antisymmetric function over symmetric interval.

Integrals over lines (2) and (4) go to zero as $M \to \infty$. So, we have now, via residuals theorem

$$
2 \pi i \, \mathrm{res} \; \frac{\cos a x}{\cosh x} = \lim\limits_{M \to \infty} \int\limits_{\gamma_M} \frac{\cos a x}{\cosh x} \, dx = (1 + \cos (a \pi i)) \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos a x}{\cosh x} \, dx
$$

$$\int\limits_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos a x}{\cosh x} \, dx =  \pi i \, \mathrm{res} \; \frac{\cos a x}{\cosh x} * \frac{1}{(1 + \cos (a \pi i))}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume $a>0$. By geometric series we have
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{\cosh(x)}\,dx &=& 2\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\int_{0}^{+\infty}\cos(ax) e^{-(2n+1)x}\,dx\\&=&2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(2n+1)(-1)^n}{a^2+(2n+1)^2}\end{eqnarray*}$$
and we may notice that
$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=(2n+1)}\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sec\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)=(-1)^{n+1} $$
so by invoking [Herglotz' trick](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/581162/how-does-the-herglotz-trick-work) we get:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{\cosh(x)}\,dx = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2\cosh\frac{\pi a}{2}}}. $$