# Contour integration of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\cos x}{\cosh x} \,{\rm d}x$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

> Using contour integration, find $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2\cos x}{\cosh x} \,{\rm d}x$$

---

How to calculate it? I never worked with integrals of this type.

[image: I don't know how to rewrite the function(my photo)]

Comment: This is obviously an exercise. What have you tried to do?

Comment: @KBS So I found contour but don't know how to transform function(New link)

Comment: Hint: use $\displaystyle J(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos ax}{\cosh x} \,dx=\Re\,\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{i ax}}{\cosh x} \,dx$, then your integral $I=-\frac{d^2}{da^2}J(a)\Big|_{a=1}$. For $J(a)$ use your rectangular contour: at $\displaystyle x\to x+\pi i\quad \frac{e^{i ax}}{\cosh x}\to -\,e^{-\pi a}\frac{e^{i ax}}{\cosh x}$

Comment: @Svyatoslav I am going to try it, thank you! (Are you from NSU :) ?)

Comment: You mean the Novosibirsk State University (NGU) in Akademgorodok? Yes; I was graduated in 1988 as a physicist :)

Comment: @Svyatoslav it was unexpected to see your hint, I'm currently studying at NSU :)

Comment: I wish you good luck! If you need some reasonable assistance, and I'm able help - I would be glad; please ask :) I wish you a nice day!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544300/evaluating-int-0-infty-frac-cos-ax-coshxdx?rq=1

Comment: @xpaul I already solved it :)